# The earthern ring reputation gain from mobs?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I need to get reputation with Earthern Ring but I can't get it anymore from quests and tabard(championing) is excluded. However, I know that killing certain mobs in some areas grant reputation with certain factions.

So my question is:"Do mobs that grant reputation with earthern ring exist, and if so, which ones?"

P.S.:I don't care about other ways of getting reputation with them, I just need to know if it is possible to get reputation by killing mobs(like it works with other factions).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say but the only way you can gain reputation with Earthen Ring after completing the quests from Vashj'ir, Deepholm, the Twilight Highlands and Thrall quest line from 4.2 is with championing by wearing there tabard and doing dungeons.

Sources: [wowpedia.org](http://www.wowpedia.org/Earthen_Ring#Gaining_Reputation), [wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1135/the-earthen-ring#comments) and [tentonhammer](http://www.tentonhammer.com/wow/guides/reputation/cataclysm/earthen-ring#4)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you start stacking rep at Vash'jir, and you can manage throu friendly with it. Then you move to Twilight Highlands and Deepholm. There are dailies quests in those places, just there is no "earthen ring" zone or earthen ring mobs around the world. If you're avoiding championing, you just have to grind these quests, and nothing else.

PS: i made only to revered with questing, but maybe i just missed out some quests